# Wrap resources inside custom class and invoke class?

Tags: nginx, puppet

I am using Puppet 3.0. I tried to use the existing NGINX module but encountered one issue which no answer seems to exist. I have moved to implementing NGINX module myself which handles my exact requirements.

Each package/service/file resource works as expected and now I am moving the code out of init.pp into a /manifest/nginx.pp fileas a class:

```
class company_nginx {

  ... Various resources

}
```

Now I am trying to include this class inside the init.pp

```
include company_nginx
```

An it returns an error:

> Error: Could not find class nginx for localhost on node localhost

What step or concept am I missing? How do I invoke this "class" in the init.pp file to get the resources invoked and configuring a system???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manifest file names and the classes defined within them must *exactly* match. If you want to have a class names `company_nginx` then it must be in a file names `company_nginx.pp`.

This required comes from the [puppet autoloader](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_namespaces.html).

Comment: That's what I thought but I tried with just nginx and it still didn't work?

Comment: What is the full path of the file, and what is the name of the class inside the file?

Comment: Figured it out...you HAVE to implement a module according to spec...the "module" folder must have a manifests and/or files and/or templates directories and template() or file() only get past the modulename/filename NOT the "templates" directory

Answer (score 1):

Your class names must be qualified for Puppet to be able to pick them up.

```
class nginx::company_nginx { ... }
```

This class will be loaded from module `nginx` file `manifests/company_nginx.pp`.

Doing `include company_nginx` will make Puppet assume that there is an actual module names `company_nginx` with the class defined in `init.pp`.